# Form control to set values of 'multiple' property

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco supports model properties that allow multiple values:

```
<aspect name="aspectName">
  <title>The Aspect Title</title>
  <properties>
    <property name="propname">
      <type>d:text</type>
      <multiple>true</multiple>
    </property>
  </properties>
</aspect>
```

The following `share-config-custom.xml` snippet renders this property as a single text-field:

```
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="aspectName">
  <forms>
    <form>
      <appearance>
        <field id="propname" />
      </appearance>
    </form>
  </forms>
</config>
```

Is there any configuration option to render a control that allows to edit multiple values of the property?

If not, is there a way to render such a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no builtin control - open issues: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-3144 & https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-5299

Maybe there are some community/addons control available.

Poor man's solution would be to enter comma-separated values into your default text input control.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way that you can make a text box have a list of properties but requires additional work with the .ftl. You essentially save the text as a json object and use the datatables properties to build out a table

https://github.com/craigNelson1/alfresco-datatable-property